# How to transition route from form submission in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application

I have an Ember JS (v 2.2.0) component, which has a form with a submit method.

On form submission, I want to transition to a different route. 
How do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

transitioning to different route is not usually responsibility of component you need to send action (onSubmit for example) to route which will trigger actual transition

```
{{your-component submit='onSubmitForm'}}
```

in your component

```
 actions: {
  submit() {
    this.sendAction('submit', { field1: 'val', field2: 'val' });
  }
 }
```

in your route

```
actions: {
 onSubmitForm(fields) {
   this.transitionTo('new-route');
 }
}
```

Comment: how does `onSubmitForm` get the state of the various fields in the form, which would reside inside the component at this point?

Comment: you send as parameter for the action this.sendAction('onSubmit', { field1:'val', field2: 'val' })

Comment: can you add the code for where `this.sendAction` is called in the component?